# Using 3D KML (Line Based) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, kml, 3d, kmz

I'll prefix this with stating that my abilities in GIS are lackluster and I'm still learning, it is also my first time doing any 3D work in QGIS.

I have a KMZ file that contains Z Values (Created in Autocad) which I would like to use in a 3D GIS file.

Will this require use of the "Mesh Calculator"?

Comment: No, the Mesh Calculator is used for mesh data (see https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html) and has nothing to do with 3D.